# Some pages crashes, get errors: "Uncaught TypeError: mixers is not a function & Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. "

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, framer-motion

I developed a website using react js. But some pages don't work correctly. For example, the `work` page has to work like the below. When hovering the image, it has to changed the opacity and show the anchor tags (`work` page) :

[image]

But when I open the website for the first time, the hover effects and anchor tags are not visible. However, they are still clickable. It seems like this when I hover :

[image]

Finally, the page crashes after a while when I scroll through other pages and come back. First, elements fade and then disappear. At the end, I only get blank page. I also added how the crush pages look like (the `Work` and `Skills` pages):

[image]

[image]

But, when I refresh the website, it fixes again.

I get these errors:
[image]

`Work.jsx` file:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AiFillEye, AiFillGithub } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { AppWrap, MotionWrap } from '../../wrapper';
import { urlFor, client } from '../../client';
import './Work.scss';


function Work() {

  const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState('All');

  const [animateCard, setAnimateCard] = useState({ y:0, opacity: 1 });

  const [works, setWorks] = useState([]);
  const [filterWork, setFilterWork] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "works"]'
    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setWorks(data);
      setFilterWork(data);
    })
  }, [])
  
  const handleWorkFilter = (item) => {
    setActiveFilter(item);
    setAnimateCard([{ y:100, opacity:0 }])

    setTimeout (() => {
      setAnimateCard([{ y:0, opacity: 1}])
      
      if(item === 'All') {
        setFilterWork(works)
      } else {
        setFilterWork(works.filter((work) => work.tags.includes(item)))
      }
    },500)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="head-text">MY PROJECTS</h2>

      <div className='app__work-filter'>
        {['UI/UX', 'REACT JS', 'HTML', 'JAVACRIPT', 'CSS', 'SCSS', 'ALL'].map((item, index) => 
          <div 
            className={`app__work-filter-item app__flex p-text ${activeFilter === item ? "item-active" : ""}`}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => handleWorkFilter(item)}
          >
            {item}
            
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <motion.div
        animate = {animateCard}
        transition = {{ duration: 0.5, delayChildren: 0.5 }}
        className = 'app__work-portfolio'
      >
        {filterWork.map((work, index) =>
          <div className='app__work-item app__flex' key={index}>
            <div className='app__work-img app__flex'>
              <img src={urlFor(work.imgUrl)} alt={work.name} />
              <motion.div
                whileHover={{ opacity: [0,1]}}
                transition={{ duration: 0.25, ease: 'easeInOut', staggerChildren: 0.5 }}
                className='app__work-hover app__flex'
              >
                <a href={work.projectLink} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
                  <motion.div
                    whileInView={{ scale: [0, 1]}}
                    whileHover={{ scale: [1, 0.9]}}
                    transition={{ duration: 0.25 }}
                    className='app__flex'
                  >
                    <AiFillEye />
                  </motion.div>
                </a>              
                <a href={work.codeLink} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
                  <motion.div
                    whileInView={{ scale: [0, 1]}}
                    whileHover={{ scale: [1, 0.9]}}
                    transition={{ duration: 0.25 }}
                    className='app__flex'
                  >
                    <AiFillGithub />
                  </motion.div>
                </a>
              </motion.div>
            </div>

            <div className='app__work-content app__flex'>
              <h4 className='bold-text'>{work.title}</h4>
              <p className='p-text-dark app__work-desc'>{work.description}</p>

              <div className='app__work-tag app__flex'>
                <p className='p-text-dark'>{work.tags[0]}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

      </motion.div>

    </>
    
  )  
}

export default AppWrap(
  MotionWrap(Work, 'app__works'),
  'work',
  'app__lightbluebg'
);
```

`Work.scss` file:

```js
.app__works {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

.app__work-filter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    margin: 4rem 0 2rem;

    .app__work-filter-item {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        background-color: var(--blue1-color);
        
        font-weight: 800;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        margin: 0.5rem;

        &:hover {
            background-color: var(--black-color);
            color: #fff;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
            padding: 1rem 2rem;
            border-radius: 0.85rem;
        }
    }

    .item-active {
        background-color: var(--secondary-color);
        color: #fff;
    }
}

.app__work-portfolio {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    .app__work-item{
        width: 290px;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 2rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        background-color: var(--blue1-color);
        color: #000;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;

        z-index: 0;

        &:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
            width: 470px;
            padding: 1.25rem;
            border-radius: 0.75rem;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 1rem;
        }
    }
}

.app__work-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
    position: relative;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        object-fit: cover;
        
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        height: 350px;
    }
}

.app__work-hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

    div {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        color: white;
        margin: 1rem;
        font-family: var(--font-base);
        font-weight: 800;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;

        svg {
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            color: var(--white-color);
        }
    }
}

.app__work-content {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;

    h4 {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
    .app__work-desc {
        margin-top: 10px;
        height: 35px;
    }
    .app__work-tag {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: var(--blue1-color);
        top: -25px;
    }
}
```

`Skills.jsx` file:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactToolTip from 'react-tooltip';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { AppWrap, MotionWrap } from '../../wrapper';
import { urlFor, client } from '../../client';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import './Skills.scss';

function Skills() {

  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([])
  const [experiences, setExperiences] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "experiences"]';
    const skillsQuery = '*[_type == "skills"]';

    client.fetch(skillsQuery).then((data) => {
      setSkills(data);
    })
    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setExperiences(data);
    })
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="head-text">SKILLS & EXPERIENCE</h2>

      <div className='app__skills-container'>
        <motion.div className='app__skills-list'>
          {skills?.map((skill, index) => (
            <motion.div
              whileInView={{opacity: [0, 1]}}
              transition={{duration: 0.5}}
              className='app__skills-item app__flex'
              key={skill.name}
            >
              <div className='app__flex' style={{ backgroundColor: skill.bgColor }}>
                <img src={urlFor(skill.icon)} alt={skill.name}/>
              </div>
              <p className='p-text'>{skill.name}</p>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </motion.div>

        <motion.div className='app__experiences-list'>

          {experiences?.map((experience) => (
            <motion.div
              className='app__experiences-item'
              key={experience.year}
            >
              <div className='app__experiences-year'>
                <p className='bold-text'>{experience.year}</p>
                
              </div>
              <motion.div
                className='app__experiences-works'
              >
                {experience.works.map((work) => (
                  <>
                    <motion.div
                      whileInView={{opacity: [0, 1]}}
                      transition={{duration: 0.5}}
                      className='app__experiences-work-item'
                      data-tip 
                      data-for={work.name}
                      key={work.name}
                    >
                      <h4 className='bold-text'>{work.name}</h4>
                      <p className='p-text-dark'>{work.company}</p>
                    </motion.div> 
        
                    <ReactToolTip
                      id = {work.name}
                      effect = 'solid'
                      arrowColor = '#fff'
                      className = 'skills-tooltip'
                    >
                      {work.desc}
                    </ReactToolTip>
                  </>   
                ))}
              </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
          
          ))}

        </motion.div>

      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default AppWrap(
  MotionWrap(Skills, 'app__skills'),
  'skills',
  'app__darkbluebg'
);
```

`Skills.scss` file:

```js
.app__skills {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.app__skills-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3rem;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    

    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.app__skills-list {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-right: 5rem;

    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
        margin-right: 0;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        
    }
}

.app__skills-item {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1rem;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

    div {
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: var(--blue1-color);

        img {
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;

        }
        &:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    p {
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 0.5rem;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        margin: 1rem 2rem;
        
        p {
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }
    }
}

.app__experiences-list {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;

    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }
}

.app__experiences-item {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.app__experiences-works {
    flex: 1;

    .app__experiences-work-item {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        cursor: pointer;

        h4 {
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 0.8rem;
            margin-top: 5px; 
        }
    }
}

.app__experiences-year {
    margin-right: 2rem;


    p {
        font-weight: 800;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
        margin-right: 1rem;
    }
}

.skills-tooltip {
    max-width: 300px !important;
    background-color: var(--white-color) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    padding: 1rem !important;
    color: var(--gray-color) !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    line-height: 1.5 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;

    @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        font-size: 1.75rem !important;
        max-width: 500px !important;
        line-height: 2 !important;
    }
}
```

`Appwrap.js` file:

```js
import { color } from '@mui/system';
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationDots, SocialMedia } from '../components';


const AppWrap = (Component, idName, classNames) => function HOC() {
  return (
    <div id={idName} className={`app__container ${classNames}`}>
        <SocialMedia />

        <div className='app__wrapper app__flex'>
            <Component />

            <div className='copyright'>
                <p className='p-text'>@2022 AYGEN</p>
                <p className='p-text'>All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>


        <NavigationDots active={idName} />


    </div>
    
  )
}

export default AppWrap;
```

`MotionWrap.js` file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

const MotionWrap = (Component, classNames) => function HOC() {
  return (
    <motion.div
        whileInView={{ y: [100, 50, 0], opacity: [0, 0, 1] }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        className={`${classNames} app__flex`}
    >
        <Component />
    </motion.div>
  )
}

export default MotionWrap
```

I hope I can explain this clearly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. probably one of you .map functions passes undefined as key, and by so you are getting the error. 2. try using `z-index: 999` on your hovered elements

Comment: I just saw that I wrote ```'JAVACRIPT'``` instead of ```'JAVASCRIPT'``` in ```.map``` function on ```work.jsx``` file. I fixed that and added ```z-index: 999``` but It didn't work. I get the same errors and problems.

Comment: i would have print the keys i pass to the first element in every map, you will find the problem there. about the z-index, is the element u are adding z-index to is relative positioned?

Comment: If I get what you mean I check the keys written inside divs below of all map functions in ```Skills.jsx```.  Each key is different from the others and I can't see the problem and fix it. But it seems ```Skills.jsx``` is the only reason for crashes. If I delete the Skills section, I only get **"Uncaught TypeError: mixers[mixerIndex] is not a function"** error, but all crashes fix. No more faded or blank pages. About the hover effect, I added z-index into ```app__work-hover``` class in ```work.scss```. Its position is absolute. However, if I change position to relative, it still don't work.

Comment: `experience.year`, does it promise that every year is different? is there a way there are the same years value in different experiences?

Comment: same goes for `work.name` and `skill.name`

Comment: about the `app__work-hover` class, you are using framer-motion which im not so 
familiar with, your element has: `opacity: 0;` which means its not visible and still clickable, you should also remove its `pointer-events` when hidden so it wont be clickable. and you can just use css transition to change opacity of an element on hover and its super easy and will save you the trouble.

Comment: I checked all keys of Skills. It seems the problem is only because of ```experience``` inside of ```Skills.jsx```, not because of ```Skills```. I can't figure out the problem but when I delete the experience, the errors are gone. However, I had added only one experience, so ```work.name``` or ```experience.year``` can't be different. Maybe there is a problem with Sanity. I'm going to delete it completely and re-write it.

Comment: On the other hand, I edited ```app__work-hover``` as you described. Removed the ```pointer-events``` and added "on hover" effects. It works correctly now. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad it helped. anyway, if there are more that one work.name can be more with the same value, so the u will get the warning about the keys, that it should be unique.